# Rerendering React components after redux state's locale has updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-intl

I've implemented `Redux` in my `React` application, and so far this is working great, but I have a little question.

I have an option in my navbar to change the `locale`, stored in `redux's state`. When I change it, I expect every component to rerender to change traductions. To do this, I have to specify

`locale: state.locale`

in the `mapStateToProps` function... Which leads to a lot of code duplication.

Is there a way to implicitly pass locale into the props of every component `connect`ed with `react-redux` ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redux implements a [shouldComponentUpdate](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connect.js#L76) that prevents a component from updating unless it's props are changed.

In your case you could ignore this check by passing `pure=false` to `connect`:

```js
connect(select, undefined, undefined, { pure: false })(NavBar);
```

For performance reasons this is a good thing and probably isn't what you want.

Instead I would suggest writing a custom connect function that will ensure `locale` is always added to your component props:

```js
const localeConnect = (select, ...connectArgs) => {
  return connect((state, ownProps) => {
    return {
      ...select(state, ownProps),
      locale: state.locale
    };
  }, ...connectArgs);
};

// Simply use `localeConnect` where you would normally use `connect`
const select = (state) => ({ someState: state.someState });

localeConnect(select)(NavBar);  // props = { someState, locale }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind but couldn't figure out a way to rewrite the connect function... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello, are you sure the code you gave me manages ownProps ?
At some places in my code I replaced connect with localeConnect, but sometimes ownProps is undefined, and when I use connect again and specify locale in mapStateToProps to make it work, it's not... Thanks in advance!

Comment: My apologies, I haven't used redux with props in a select before (some required reading filled me in!). It seems that using the spread operator worked on the first render, but not the 2nd. I've tested with just specifying `state` and `ownProps` and this seems to work. Updated the code, hope this works for you too!

Comment: Hello, it now works like a charm, thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

To cut down the duplication of code I usually just pass an arrow function to the connect method when mapping state to props, looks cleaner to me.  Unfortunately though, I don't think there is another way to make it implicit as your component could subscribe to multiple store "objects".

```
export default connect((state) => ({
  local: state.locale
}))(component);
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you can set the [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) of your parent component, and use it in your child components.  This is what Redux uses to supply the store's `state` and `dispatch` function to connected React components.

In your Parent component, implement `getChildContext` and specify each variable's `PropType`.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    getChildContext() {
        return {
            test: 'foo'
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child />
                <Child />
            </div>
        );
    }

}

Parent.childContextTypes = {
    test: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

In your Child component, use `this.context.test` and specify its `PropType`.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>Child - Context: {this.context.test}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Child.contextTypes = {
    test: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsbin.com/potilakozu/edit?js,output) of it working.

I might as well mention that, while libraries like Redux use this, React's documentation states that this is an advanced and experimental feature, and may be changed/removed in future releases.  I personally would not recommend this approach instead of simply passing the information you need in `mapStateToProps`, like you originally mentioned.

Comment: Hello and thanks for this answer. I was aware of that possibility, but it involves more code duplication, and doesn't really solve the fact that I have to explicitly pass my variable to each of my components... Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following what you're saying - the example I posted demonstrates that you don't have to explicitly pass a variable to child components by using React's Context feature.  In my `render` function for the Parent component, the Child components are being rendered with no props - it's assumed that any child of the Parent will implicitly have access to the context.

Comment: Yeah but you have to write `ChildrenComponent.contextTypes = { test: React.PropTypes.string };` for each child component you wish to have the context passed to props... It's the same as specifying it in `mapStateToProps`